# How to Create a form by integrating Python,XML & Html

Tags: python

I created an XML file & a Python file.
Using the Python file i'm able to print the attributes to terminal but i'm unable to write that values on html page.

Comment: What's your question? Please provide more detail and tell us what your specific problem is.

Comment: can you provide more details on input and output?